# Remove blank space from Dash plotly grouped bar graph

Tags: python

Plolty graph showing blank spaces in the group itself(NOT  between the 2 groups) if data is missing for some reasons in grouped bar graph
Want to get continuos bars in a group without gap

Comment: Your description is good but I believe for the question to be complete it would be good to have the snippet of code that you have currently. It makes it way easier for people to give you punctual advice.

Comment: please provide code and where the error is thrown.